# I am getting 'No memory for the experiment' error although i dont see any mistake

Tags: python, qiskit

I am trying to execute this code but I am getting this error as 'No memory for the experiment' . Can anyone help me out is there anything else I need to import to get the memory of circuit?

````
from qiskit.providers.aer import QasmSimulator
# Create a quantum circuit
qc = QuantumCircuit(2, 2)
qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0, 1)
qc.measure([0, 1], [0, 1])
# Get the Qasm simulator and set the backend options
aer_qasm_simulator = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
# Set the backend options, method set to statevector
options = {'method': 'statevector', 'memory' : True, 'shots':10}
# Execute circuit using the backend options created
job = execute(qc, backend_simulator, backend_options=options)
result = job.result()
# Pull the memory slots for the circuit
memory = result.get_memory(qc)
# Print the results from the memory slots
print('Memory results: ', memory)```
````

Comment: Bumped into this as well! Following Loredo's book by any chance? There's quite some changes against what's in there compared to what's online now in IBM Quantum Experience. I have the 2020 print from a couple of months ago. A November 2023 edition is out now. I hope with up to date code references and corrected typos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `memory` and `shots` are not backend options, but `execute` parameters:

```py
# Set the backend options, method set to statevector
options = {'method': 'statevector'}
# Execute circuit using the backend options created
job = execute(qc, aer_qasm_simulator, backend_options=options, memory=True, shots=10)
```

That would fix your issue.

Side note: Qiskit is [moving away from the `execute` model](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/pull/7892) because, among other things, it creates this kind of confusions.

The current (May 2022) way of doing what you are doing is the following:

```py
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, Aer, transpile
from qiskit.providers.aer import QasmSimulator

# Create a quantum circuit
qc = QuantumCircuit(2, 2)
qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0, 1)
qc.measure([0, 1], [0, 1])

# Get the statevector simulator
aer_simulator_statevector = Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator_statevector')

# Transpile for the backend. Strictly speacking, not necesary in this case
qc = transpile(qc, aer_simulator_statevector)

# Pull the memory slots for the circuit
result = aer_simulator_statevector.run(qc, shots=10, memory=True).result()
memory = result.get_memory(qc)

# Print the results from the memory slots
print('Memory results: ', memory)
```

Welcome to the StackOverflow community :)